# NPE occurs when add an object in Array of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

How do I resolve this problem...

I wanna add object `OrgDO` in `allOrgListArr[idx]`.

```
ArrayList<OrgDO>[] allOrgListArr = new ArrayList[Integer.parseInt(maxLv)+1];

for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(maxLv)+1; i++) {
    allOrgListArr[i] = new ArrayList<OrgDO>();
}
            
for(OrgDO org : allOrgList.getOrgListList()) {
    allOrgListArr[org.getORG_LEVEL()].add(org); // --> this part throws a NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: you understand that this: org.getORG_LEVEL() might lead to non-existent elements? Also: if this is all your code, I'm impressed it compiles: what is allOrgList supposed to be?

Comment: @땡Q풋조이 is it possible that it's one of those `org` that is null? I mean, have you checked that `allOrgList.getOrgListList()` doesn't contain any null element?

Comment: @Stultuske This is a part of the code that converts list to tree. I want to make a tree without full-search, because I know all nodes' level. So I think I can make a tree with searching only nodes who have that level.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No, all org have at least an element

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit more defensive in your programming and check that the index exists in the array and if so you also need to check that you have an object at that index

```
for(OrgDO org : allOrgList.getOrgListList()) {
    int level = org.getORG_LEVEL();
    if (level >= allOrgListArr.length()) {
        continue; //or other error handling
    }

    List<OrgDO> list = allOrgListArr[level];
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<OrgDO>();
        allOrgListArr[level] = list;
    }
    
    list.add(org);
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why my code occurs npe.. I initialize allOrgListArr using ArrayList<OrgDO> at first line but it doesn't work... When I do your method, it works...